# handling high dimension tables

Tags: r

I have a table that I routinely compute with R that has three dimensions. I would like to add some tables within the (here 5) marginal tables. What I usually do is like:

```
    A=sample(LETTERS[1:5],100, rep=T)

    b=sample(letters[1:2],100, rep=T)

    numbers=sample(1:3,100, rep=T)

   ( tab=table(A,b,numbers) )
   ( tab1=ftable(addmargins(tab)) )
```

I would like to add the sum of the first few marginal tables and then the sum of the remaining tables  at the bottom, then the grand total. I can imagine that in the resulting ftable I would want the As,Bs,Cs, then the sum of those three, then the Ds, Es, and the sum of those two, then the sum of all of the tables, like:

```
         numbers   1   2   3 Sum
    A   b                          
    A   a             1   5   0   6
        b             4   2   2   8
        Sum           5   7   2  14
    B   a             2   6   6  14
        b             5   4   5  14
        Sum           7  10  11  28
    C   a             3   2   5  10
        b             1   2   2   5
        Sum           4   4   7  15
  sumac a             6  13  11  30   #### how do i add these three lines
        b               ....
        sum             ....
    D   a             2   1   1   4
        b             4   5   3  12
        Sum           6   6   4  16
    E   a             5   3   4  12
        b             4   3   8  15
        Sum           9   6  12  27
  sumde a             7   4   5  20   #### and these
        b               ....
        sum               ....
  sumae a            13  17  16  46
        b            18  16  20  54
        Sum          31  33  36 100
```

As usual I think the solution is prolly many fewer lines than the question. Thanks
Seth Latimer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
isABC<-ifelse(A %in% c("A", "B", "C"), "ABC", "CD")
( tab=table(isABC,A,b,numbers) )
( tab1=ftable(addmargins(tab)) )
```

Now you have a larger table which holds even more rows than you want, but those should be easy to drop...

Comment: Thanks to Nick for the help, but I found a solution using abind(). I just compute the sum and abind it to the table ala:` sumac=tab[1,,]+tab[2,,]+tab[3,,]  
sumde=tab[4,,]+tab[4,,]   
sumae=sumac+sumde

tab1=abind(tab,sumac,along=1)
tab1=abind(tab,sumde,along=1)
tab1=abind(tab,sumae,along=1)

ftable(tab1)`